# Phonegap html table

Tags: html-table, iscroll

I need to make a scrollable table with fixed header row and header column in an phonegap app using html, javascript and css.

I have studied a number of existing questions, and based on the below solution (http://jsbin.com/bojacelaba/1/edit?html,css,output),
I have prepared the following file:

http://www.ksutopia.com/a2.html

This file has a fixed row header and a scrollbar, and it has rendered properly in the firefox browser/android emulator. However, if I run this in the actual device (Samsung Note 1 with android 4.1.2), the row header is blanked.

http://www.ksutopia.com/screenshot.png

Anyone can give me any hint on this would be deeply appreciated. I have read a lot of answer to use iscroll. I try to look at it but there is no example of "fixed header with scrollbar". It would be grateful if someone can point to an appropriate example / tutorial.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

u have to use jquery.

for example,

**

```
<table id="tableId"> 
    <thead>
        <th>Column Header 01</th>
        <th>Column Header 02</th>
        <th>Column Header 03</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
        <td>Column Content</td>
        <td>Column Content</td>
        <td>Column Content</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
       $('#tableId').tableScroll({height:600});
});
</script>
</body>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

After a couple days of research, I finally find out a tutorial that suit my purpose:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/

hope it would suit your needs as well.